# Is there a bound on the number of irreducible components in terms of the (arithmetic) genus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a reduced projective curve over a field $k$.

> Is there a bound on the number of irreducible components of $X$ in terms of its arithmetic genus $p_a(X) = 1- \chi_k(\mathcal{O}_X)$?

Or are those two invariants absolutely not related?

Comment: A chain of lines of arbitrary length is a curve of genus $0$ with arbitrarily many irreducible components. Replacing one of the lines with a smooth curve of genus $g$ gives an example of arbitrary genus with equally arbitrarily many components.